# c#: how to convert image field to int[]?

Tags: c#

c#:
How would you convert an image field's data to an int array?
How would you write an int array to an image field?

Has to be done in code, not procedures, I don't know which database type will be used.

Edit: I am using a blob field to store a one dimensional array of instrument readings.

Comment: Please explain the context - what do you mean "image"? You mean the SQL Server data type?

Comment: Yes a blob field in sql server for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work. I wonder how portable it is?

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    int[] intArray = { 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42, 108, 342, 815, 1087, 6717 };

    byte[] inputBytes = new byte[intArray.GetLength(0) * 4];

    Buffer.BlockCopy(intArray, 0, inputBytes, 0, intArray.GetLength(0) * 4);

    int[] outputInts = new int[intArray.GetLength(0)];

    Buffer.BlockCopy(inputBytes, 0, outputInts, 0, intArray.GetLength(0) * 4);

    Assert.IsTrue(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(intArray, outputInts));

}
```

Comment: Please use .Length instead of .GetLength(0) for single-dimension arrays - it's much more idiomatic. Other than that, it should work so long as the endianness is the same everywhere. It does just copy the bytes between the arrays though - no conversion. Basically endianness is *the* potential flaw.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean a SQL Server Image, typically you'll get this as a byte array or possibly as a stream. (You can wrap a byte array in a `MemoryStream`.)

You could either use `BinaryReader` around a stream or `BitConverter` with a byte array to convert an integer at a time, or use `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy the data from a `byte[]` into an `int[]`.

Comment: I found those methods but am concerned about endian issues. The real question should really be 'what is the most efficient way to store instrumentation readings in a relational database. Readings such as one sweep of a digital oscilloscope?

Comment: If you want to take care of endianness, you could use my EndianBinaryReader and EndianBitConverter in MiscUtil (http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil). Your broader question isn't one I have a particularly good answer to, I'm afraid - other than "make sure the format is well-defined."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain what you're asking, but if you want to access the internal bit data of an image, this is how you do it.

Note the following below:

I explicitly set the `PixelFormat` rather than using `bmp.ImageFormat`. This will throw an exception if the format I picked isn't compatible with the bitmap, but at least i know how many bpp I'm getting.

I'm locking the bits in `ImageLockMode.ReadOnly` mode, so I can't copy the bits back in to the image. If I want to *modify* the bits in the image, I simply use `ReadWrite` mode instead, and then after I'm done manipulating the bits, I copy them back in to the `BitmapData` object, then unlock the `Bitmap`.

Finally, I'm copying the data out *twice* -- first as a byte[] array, and second as an Int32[] array. Normally you only do it once, and normally you use a byte array. But since you specifically said int[], I included both examples.

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("myimage.jpg");
BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
    PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

// copy as bytes
int byteCount = data.Stride * data.Height;
byte[] bytes = new byte[byteCount];
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, bytes, 0, byteCount);

// -- OR -- copy as ints
int wordCount = byteCount / 4;
Int32[] words = new Int32[wordCount];
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, words, 0, wordCount);

bmp.UnlockBits(data);
```

Comment: I am using a blob field to store a one dimensional array of instrument readings.